# Make own image dataset like tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

During the normalization process of Images using `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`
as

```
# Train Dataset
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
train_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'train_test_data/train/',
        target_size=(45,45),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')
# and Test dataset

# Test Dataset or validation 
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_dataset = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train_test_data/val',
    target_size  =(45,45),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
)
```

The original dataset : [Maths Handwritten](https://www.kaggle.com/xainano/handwrittenmathsymbols)
How is it possible to make like same return like

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

CNN model

```
# CNN model
cnn = tf.keras.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters =32 , kernel_size =3  , activation='relu' , input_shape = [45,45,3]))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D( strides = 2,pool_size=2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3 , activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(strides = 2, pool_size  =2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units  = 128 , activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units  = 128 , activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units  =82  ,activation  ='softmax'))
```

The image has dimension `45 * 45` and total `82 classes`.
I want it because there was some errors usign the above `ImageDataGenerator` but the model ran fluently with builtin function `load_data()` . Or is

Comment: What is the process of making it , the return types says 
`x_train: uint8 NumPy array of grayscale image data with shapes (50000, 32, 32, 3), containing the training data. Pixel values range from 0 to 255.`

Comment: You want numpy arrays basically?

Comment: I think yes , I'm confused with how to do it

Comment: I will try it and then return to you 

Comment: Dataset is bit huge about 300,000 + images for train

Comment: Did you check TFDS CLI on creating custom Dataset ? https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset